# Executing native code from a Java alarm using BroadcastReceiver, on Android

Tags: java, android, java-native-interface, broadcastreceiver

First, I am new at Android and Java, so I am doing most of my stuff in native code. I am doing this mostly for speed reason, as my code has to deal with image processing.

My application is a timelapse camera, where it has to wake up every once in a while, acquire a wakelock, take some pictures, process them, set a new alarm then go to sleep.

My alarm receiver code looks like so:

```
public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private static final String TAG = "Something";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "We got alarm :)");

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                CameraActivity.cameraraw.call_alarm();  }
        }).start();
}
```

CameraActivity.cameraraw.call_alarm(); just calls a JNI function and then gives the control to my c code, which looks like so:

```
JNIEXPORT jbyte JNICALL Java_com_example_android_camera2raw_Camera2RawFragment_rtc_1alarm(JNIEnv* env,jclass clazz,jobject cameraraw)
{
    syslog(LOG_CRIT, "Alarm in native code, picture %s",cur_timelapse_pic);

    wake_me_up(env,clazz,cameraraw);

    sleep(5);

    if(cur_timelapse_pic<timelapse_shots)
    {
        do_focus_stack(env,clazz,cameraraw,cur_timelapse_pic);
        cur_timelapse_pic++;
        set_alarm(env,clazz,cameraraw,timelapse_delay);
    }

    go_to_sleep(env,clazz,cameraraw);
    syslog(LOG_CRIT, "Went to sleep");
}
```

The code works fine at the first alarm, but the second alarm crashes even before the syslog()

2020-04-30 18:19:00.039 15198-15727/com.example.android.camera2raw W/roid.camera2ra: 0xebadde09 skipped times: 0

```
--------- beginning of crash
```

2020-04-30 18:19:00.040 15198-15727/com.example.android.camera2raw A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x1 in tid 15727 (Thread-8), pid 15198 (roid.camera2raw)
2020-04-30 18:19:06.531 15198-15198/com.example.android.camera2raw D/ViewRootImpl@1b051d4[CameraActivity]: Surface release. android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewRootHandler.handleMessage:4825 android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage:106

Is there something I am missing? Btw, my function finishes doing it's work long before the next alarm comes.
Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: You mean to set the alarm, or to execute what happens when I get the alarm? The native code contains a web server and eventually I was thinking to embed a scripting language for people to play with the camera, as well as possibly porting it on other platforms,such as raspberry pi, so I am trying to keep most of the code native.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cur_timelapse_pic` seems to be a number, yet you are trying to log it as a string (`%s`). Change that to `%d` or `%u` instead.

Comment: I can't believe I missed that! I spent so much time looking in the wrong place, and it was the logging command that was bad :D Thank you very much for spotting it!